# Are there instances where "!undefined" ends up being falsey? How can I work around this?

Tags: javascript

I was always under the impression that the value 'undefined' was one of the so-called 'falsey' values, and that thus negating it with '!' would cause it to become truthy.  However, I have a piece of code that is meant to return a message.  However, if the message ends up undefined, it's supposed to return 'false' instead (for rendering purposes).  The code snippet is as follows:

```
    if (!decodedMessage) {
      return !!decodedMessage;
    }
    return decodedMessage;
```

I reason that, if decodedMessage is an actual string, then "!decodedMessage" will evaluate to false, thus skipping that conditional statement right to the final return.  However, if decodedMessage is undefined, then "!decodedMessage" will evaluate to true to enter the conditional statement and return "!!decodedMessage" which I figured would be false.  Needless to say, this is not working out this way at all, hence the console log statement.  However, the console log confuses me the most here, as it logs `undefined false` to the console, which I am interpreting to mean "decodedMessage = undefined" and "!decodedMessage = false".  Is there something I am overlooking?  What would be a better way to handle undefined like this?

Edit: The full code for the function is as follows:

```
  function polybiusDecode(input) {
    let decodedMessage = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i += 2) {
      let charCodeProxy = input[i].toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0);
      while (
        charCodeProxy < 47 ||
        (charCodeProxy > 57 && charCodeProxy < 97) ||
        charCodeProxy > 122
      ) {
        decodedMessage += input[i];
        i++;
        if (i >= input.length) break;
        else charCodeProxy = input[i].toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0);
      }
      if (i >= input.length) break;
      if (input[i] === "/") {
        decodedMessage += input[i + 1];
        continue;
      }
      decodedMessage += polybiusTable[input[i] - 1][input[i + 1] - 1];
    }
    console.log(decodedMessage, !decodedMessage);
    if (!decodedMessage) {
      return !!decodedMessage;
    }
    return decodedMessage;
  }
```

Comment: can you add code to the question that actually produces the result you think you see? as it is, that code doesn't log anything, so, who knows what you're really doing

Comment: `{const undefined = true; console.log(!undefined); // false}` also, make sure your code isn't accidentally setting undefined to a truthy value within a scope like this example

Answer (score 2):

It could be that the string is composed of the characters `'undefined'`.

```js
const decodedMessage = 'undefined';
console.log(Boolean(decodedMessage));
```

If this is the case, consider fixing the code that creates `decodedMessage` by having undefined become an actual `undefined` value, rather than a string.

A workaround would be to check against `'undefined'` explicitly, but that's a bit of an X/Y approach. (`decodedMessage === 'undefined'`)

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  If I had initialized decodedMessage earlier as
const decodedMessage = "";
would that have caused undefined to end up being cast as a string?